# Google page speed up module combine_css

Tags: css, performance, .htaccess, web

Hello i use google PageSpeed Module and i created a .htaccess file in order to speed up my page (www.anetoi.com). I want to combine my css and i use combine_css without results.Im follwing google instructions without results.I think somthing is going wrong with my htaccess file.
It dos not work for me.What i do wrong?Can you suggest me a default htaccess file to use for my site or any other ways to combine all my css files into one easy?Please help i have really stack with this.Thanks in advance.
    Google's example says that if i have for example four css styling files in my page:

```
Then it rewrites it to one single file like this, using combine_css 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/yellow.css+blue.css+big.css+bold.css.pagespeed.cc.xo4He3_gYf.css">

Here is my code so far...
<IfModule pagespeed_module>
ModPageSpeed on
ModPagespeedRewriteLevel PassThrough
ModPagespeedEnableFilters combine_css,extend_cache,rewrite_images
ModPagespeedEnableFilters rewrite_css,rewrite_javascript
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the Minify PHP5 app to combine and minify your CSS and JS files.
It's BSD Licensed and you can find it hosted at Google.

https://code.google.com/p/minify/